# Add a comma after each word from an array in a twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to put a variable between each array value when I display it via Twig.

Here is my code :

```
{% for genre in genres %}
    {% for namez in genre.name|split(', ') %}
        <span>{{ namez }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Strcutre of Array *genres* :

```
array (size=2)
  0 =>
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Documentaire' (length=12)
      'movie_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'genre_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  1 =>
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Animation' (length=9)
      'movie_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'genre_id' => string '3' (length=1)
```

My results: *Documentaries Action Drama*

Instead of: *Documentary, Action, Drama*

And maybe even if it is possible to apply the sort() PHP function on the Twig / PHP split() function.

Comment: Don't do this kind of logic in the template. Send data into the template already sorted. Also, first you split by comma and then want to add a comma?

Comment: Ok for sort() :) No, i want add comma on genre.name value of my array genres

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're trying to do. Can you provide a sample of the `genres` structure?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, I edited my question by adding the structure of the Array `genres`. I just want to add commas between each value, as I will do with `explode` in PHP but this is with Twig.

Comment: I believe you meant `implode`. Twig has [`join`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/join.html), but you can't use it like you intended (inside the loop), you'd have to extract all the titles and then call `join` on them. In a loop you'd have to manually concatenate a comma to all elements except the last.

Comment: Yes, implode, decidedly.... ^^ I have try with `join` as you suggested but i can't display correctly :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely do this in one go without a loop, using the [`map`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/map.html) filter.

```
{{ genres | map(genre => "#{genre.name}") | join(', ') }}
```

Would, with your example array, give:

```
Documentaire, Animation
```

<sup>*This is testable here: https://twigfiddle.com/sjd56x*</sup>

Answer (score 3):

you cannot extract values of specific subkeys from an array in twig. You can use the loop variable do do what you wish

```
{% for genre in genres %}
    {{ genre.name }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html

Comment: I didn't know we can't extract values of specific subkeys from an array in twig. So thank you it works and I'll look into it further.

Comment: Actually, you can, with a map, see my answer

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε very nice! Your answer is better than mine!

Answer (score 1):

Try with loop

```
{% for genre in genres %}
    {{ genre.name }} {{ not loop.last ? ',' }}
{% endfor %}
```